# i++ still working for immutable Integer in Java?

Tags: java, integer

I know Integer is immutable in Java. But I tried this:

```
Integer i = 4;
i++;
System.out.println(i); // output is 5
```

Why the self-increment is still working? Did Java create a new Integer object?

Comment: You've answered the question yourself.

Comment: All are mutable in Java except string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
i = i + 1;
```

which `i` now refers to a different `Integer` object (`5`).

Comment: `i++` is NOT equivalent to that. `i++` returns the original value, not the new value.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII can you ealaborate it's quite confusing....

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Internally, both compile to `i = Integer.valueOf(i.intValue() + 1)`, so it is actually a different object.  Calls to `hashCode()` both before and after the incrementation can verify this as well.

Comment: @pinkpanther the thing about `i++` is that it's a post-increment, meaning that the value changes *after* the statement it's included in executes.

Comment: @Vulcan It's important to note the side effects of `i++`, however, making this post misleading.

Comment: @Vulcan - I would think (hope) that hashCode would return a value based on the value of the number, whether immutable or not.